# embed bokeh server in jupyter notebook running in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I want to embed a bokeh server inside Jupyter Notebook. This has been done in [this example file](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.4.3/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb).

But I usually run Jupyter Notebook on Visual Studio Code rather than directly on a web browser. This causes the problem - the bokeh plot doesn't show up in Visual Studio Code as it does in a web browser.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably (still) not currenty possible https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10765#issuecomment-739543791 (and may never be)